# Grails HTML Code -- Further Reading?

Tags: html, grails

So I've done some reading on grails, mainly on object and the relationships, etc, so I get how to create domain classes and controllers and how they work and everything, but the connection I haven't made yet is how you can take that and design a working HTML interface and useable website with that. Can anyone suggest some further reading on that. I know I need to look more into how to use GSP's and stuff, but what else? Thanks in advance.

Links to websites rather than books would be preferable, but books are good too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get started with basic scaffolding, the user guide discusses this in Chapter 16 at http://grails.org/doc/latest/ - you can either customize the dynamic scaffolding ('static scaffold = true') or run generate-all and edit the generated controller and views.

Dave Klein's book is a good intro and highly rated: [http://www.amazon.com/dp/1934356468](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356468)

Grails in Action - [http://www.amazon.com/dp/1933988932](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988932) - and The Definitive Guide to Grails 2nd ed - [http://www.amazon.com/dp/1590599950](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599950) - are also excellent and more comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the free e-book, Getting Started with Grails (http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/grails) it is not the best book on Grails I've come across but the price is right.  I learned a lot from reading The Definitive Guide to Grails and would highly recommend that one; Burt Beckwith posted the amazon link above ([http://www.amazon.com/dp/1590599950](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599950)).

Answer (score 0):

Before reading The Definitive Guide to Grails I would recommend Beginning Groovy and Grails [http://www.amazon.com/dp/1430210451](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210451). It's only the basics of the language and framework, though I didn't read it to the end, it helped me a lot :) Both are excellent reads.

Btw.: Can anyone say something about the third one: Groovy and Grails Recipes ([http://www.amazon.com/dp/143021600X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143021600X))? Good? Bad? Waste of paper?